# Simple folder encryption software

Tags: windows, encryption

I'm looking for some simple folder (and data) encryption software for my colleagues at work. I'm the IT admin, and another person has the credentials in case of substitution need.

Apart from the admins nobody else is able to look into the user-folders of `C:` (they're not that tech-savvy).

However some colleagues expressed concerns, and want their folders encrypted. Most just use `C:`, some however use `D:` which is where everybody can see everything, once they log in with their credentials, as it's not managed by the OS.

Now I know True/Vera-crypt but that's just way overkill for the need at hand. I need something more simple.

Anything out there?

Comment: Would I be correct to assume that you are speaking of multiple users of a single PC? And be very careful to ***stress*** to these "not that tech-savvy" users that if they lose their password, there is ***NO WAY*** to recover their data - because ***that is what they asked for***. But, it doesn't matter, because  ***YOU*** will be to blame when it happens, and they ***will*** complain to your manager. Seriously, just use standard Windows folder permissions, rather than encryption.

Comment: Yes, multiple users, single PC on some. Folder permissions it is.

Comment: If that's what you went with, post it as an answer & accept it (the system will allow that after 2 days)

Answer (score 2):

For simpler alternative to VeraCrypt you could use [**AxCrypt**](https://www.axcrypt.net/).

It's simple, yet powerful and open-source, too. You could even just right-click to encrypt files/folders you want to encrypt, or making encrypted files/folders decrypted over time. Decryption can be done on demand or keep decrypted while in use and re-encrypt after being modified/closed.

If you have Pro edition of Windows you could also use a feature named Encryption File System.

Comment: +1 for recommending "Encryption File System](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700811.aspx)  Note that Windows Pro licenses can be bought from about $15 from sites like https://www.kinguin.net/ or even eBay